# Поток и ожидаемые таймеры

Tags: многопоточность, таймер, ядро

Есть вот такая задача: 
Пользователь задает список, каждый элемент которого включает дату и время. Количество (пар дата / время) не ограничено.

Для каждого элемента списка создается отдельный 
поток, который в указанные пользователем дату и время открывает окно с сообщением о наступившем событии и ждет от пользователя подтверждения о прочтении. Если подтверждение не приходит в течение N секунд, то окно закрывается и повторно выдается через K секунд (N и K задаются в настройках). Если пользователь подтверждает прочтение, то поток разрушается и элемент удаляется из списка.
Для задания интервалов времени использовать таймеры ожидания.
В embarcadero реализация на с++ application form.
Может кто нибудь объяснить алгоритм с примерами кода?

```
DWORD WINAPI EventThread(LPVOID lpParameter) 
{ 
  CurrentTime=Time(); 
  CurrentDate=Date(); 
  AnsiString timeL = Form1->ListBox2->Items->Strings[counter]; 
  AnsiString dateL = Form1->ListBox1->Items->Strings[counter]; 
  AnsiString time = FormatDateTime("hh:mm:ss",CurrentTime.CurrentTime()); 
  AnsiString date = FormatDateTime("dd.MM.yyyy",CurrentDate.CurrentDate()); 
  counter++; 
  if((date == dateL) && (time == timeL))
  {
    ShowMessage(counter); 
    return 0; 
  } 
  Sleep(1); 
}
```

Comment: Сам пытаюсь сделать и ничего не получаеться

Comment: Алгоритм простой: подсчитать, через сколько наступит событие, подождать столько времени, организовать цикл: показать диалог и ждать N секунд, если диалог закрыт, оборвать ожидание и выйти из цикла, иначе подождать K секунд и вернуться к началу цикла.

Comment: А если несколько событий сразу? Оно же не покажет их пока не завершиться предыдущее

Comment: VladD, 
А если несколько событий сразу? Оно же не покажет их пока не завершиться предыдущее

Comment: @ВасилийТрофов: Если потоки разные, они выполняются независимо.

Comment: VladD, суть такая я нажимаю кнопку добавляю событие, добавил пару штук, потом нажимаю пуск и пошла проверка времени,создаваемые потоки храню в контейнере вектор. Создаю функцию которая проверяет дату и время, если совпало то создаю поток и в функции потока вывожу сообщение?